# how to do solr search including sepcial characters like (-,&.. etc)?

Tags: solr, lucene

I need to do solr search for a string like `BEBIL1407-GREEN` with special character(-) but it is ignoring - and searches for only with `BEBIL1407`. I need to search with a hole word.Im using solr_4.5.1

**Example Query :**

```
q=BEBIL1407-GREEN&qt=select&start=0&rows=24&fq=clg%3A%222%22&fq=isAproved%3A%22Y%22&fl=id
```

Comment: Are you using any tokenizers for the filed you're using in your searchs ?

Comment: <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" ><analyzer type="index"><tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/><filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" /><filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/></analyzer><analyzer type="query"><tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/><filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" /><filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/><filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/></analyzer></fieldType>

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about searching for `BEBIL1407-GREEN` but finding `BEBIL1407`.

You did not post your schem or your query parser.

As default solr using the [standard query parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser) on field "text" with fieldtype "text_general".

You can test with the solr [analysis screen](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analysis+Screen) the way from a word (in real text) to the corresponding token in the index.

For "text_general" the word "BEBIL1407-GREEN" goes to two token: "bebil1407" and "green".

The Standard-Parser does support [escaping of special characters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser#TheStandardQueryParser-EscapingSpecialCharacters) this would help if your word starts with a hyphen(minus sign). But in this case most possible the tokenizer is the reason of "finding unexpected documents".

Solution:

- You can search with a phrase. In this case `"BIBIL1407-GREEN"` will also find `"BIBIL1407 GREEN"`
- You can use an other FieldType e.g. one with [WhiteSpaceTokenizer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-WhiteSpaceTokenizer)

Hope this helps, otherwise post your search field and your definition from schema.xml...

Comment: Hi,   Im using text_general field type and the seperator is WhitespaceTokenizerFactory

Comment: <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" ><analyzer type="index"><tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/><filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" /><filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/></analyzer><analyzer type="query"><tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/><filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" /><filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/><filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/></analyzer></fieldType>

Comment: please find above snippet and am using WhitespaceTokenizerFactory for search

Comment: @sravan, so in analysis screen the generated token is only this on: 'bibil1404-green`?  Did you set the default field for search? Is this field from FieldType `text_general`?

Comment: Yes i'd set a default field in solrConfig.xml and defined it in schema.xml

Comment: So please add information to your original question: What is your default field? Does the analysis screen split the value for this special field?